# jQuery beginner question regarding slide up/down effect

Tags: .net, asp.net, jquery, effects

So I tried creating the slide up down effect like in this example,

http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/show/83-jquery-text-slide-up-slide-down-effect

The problem is, it's showing the text when the web page opens.

I want the "Paragraph" to be displayed ONLY when mouse is over it and NOT when the page first loads.

I am a completely new to jQuery, but I want to make it work.

Help?

My script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(function(){
  $('.feature_box').showFeatureText();
})

$.fn.showFeatureText = function() {
  return this.each(function(){
    var box = $(this);
    var text = $('p',this);

   // text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide();

    box.hover(function(){
      text.slideDown("slow");
    },function(){
      text.slideUp("fast");
    });

  });
}
```

HTML content

```
<div>
    <div class="feature_box" align="right">
        <h2><a href="#">Cart Details</a></h2>
        <p>
        <a href="#">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident. <BR />
        Qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum<br />
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident. <BR />
        Qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What changes do I make so that the paragraph doesn't appear by default when the page first loads?

Also, is the mouse-over effect on the `div` tag or the `p` tag? I am a bit confused. Sorry, I am really new to all this.

[EDIT]

I just made some changes, and it didn't display the paragraph when the page first loaded.

The following line was commented out.

// text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide();

Again is the mouse-over effect on `DIV` tag or `P` tag?

[EDIT 2]

Is the following line of code containing some function of jQuery or what?

```
text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide();
```

What is the "text.css"?

Comment: @happysoul Yes. `text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide()` is both positioning and hiding your paragraphs. It is equivalent to `$('p',this).css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide()`. It is important. Take a look at the code samples in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Here is the working code for the shopping cart**](http://jsfiddle.net/yfcZN/) (*make sure you edit the CSS to how you want it*). It's the same code as on the [**example page**](http://paulsturgess.co.uk/articles/show/83-jquery-text-slide-up-slide-down-effect), with the HTML from your question copy pasted in.

---

Ok, now let's go through the code.

Here is the original code from the example page in a
[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JkJuV/)

Stepping through the code...

First we call the method from inside an anonymous function using:

```
$('.feature_box').showFeatureText();
```

Since, `showFeatureText` is a method of `$('.feature_box')` we know that every time `this` is used insde `showFeatureText`, `this` is refering to all the elements with the `feature_box` class. That is one `DIV` in your case. The box of text.

Now let's step into `showFeatureText. It's being used as a short jQuery plugin. It is a method of jQuery:

```
$.fn.showFeatureText = function() {
    return this.each(function(){    
        var box = $(this);
        var text = $('p',this);

        text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide();

        box.hover(function(){
            text.slideDown("fast");
        },function(){
            text.slideUp("fast");
        });
    });
}
```

Ok, the `return this.each(function(){...})` has to be included so that the function plays nicely with the jQuery selections. In this case our jQuery selection is one DIV with the class `feature_box`, but notice that this function would work even if it were added as a method to a jQuery selection that had many elements selected, since it uses `return this.each()`. At any rate, it's enough to know that this has to be included, and it's what allows you to chain `.showFeatureText` onto `$('.feature_box')`. Ok, moving on.

```
        var box = $(this);
        var text = $('p',this);
```

These two lines just define two local variables for our convenience. `box` is `$(this)` which in this case is the  `<div class="feature_box">`. So it makes sense to call it `box`.

text are the paragraphs inside the div. This is because `('p', this)` selects all the paragraphs within `this`, and `this` is the `feature_box` div. It's basic syntax for jQuery. To select all of this within that use: `$(this, that)`. It's a little confusing, since to select id `a` and id `b` you would use `$("#a, #b")` which is completely different. Note the quotation marks.

So now `box` is synonymous with our big div `.feature_box`, and `text` is synonymous with the text inside.

Let's move on:

```
text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide();
```

We simply make all the paragraphs in the `feature_box` div invisible. `text` are the paragaphs. `.css()` assigns CSS styles to them. It positions them. Finally `hide()` makes them invisible. The CSS positioning will remain in effect essentially throughout the life of the page. Without it, the paragraphs would be below the photo.

Ok, so now that the text is all hidden, we're going to add some event handlers to our div. In other words we want to make it so that if we hover over `this` which is `$('.feature_box')`, the `.feature_box` div, then the text will appear. We also want to hide everything when we're not hovering:

```
    box.hover(function(){
        text.slideDown("fast");
    },function(){
        text.slideUp("fast");
    });
```

Notice how there are 2 functions in hover(). The first one is what happens when we mouse over the `box`. The second is what happens when we mouse out. When we hover over the div, the `text` slides down. When we stop hovering it slides back up.

And that's it. A jQuery plugin for sliding content.

You can see `each` at work on [**this jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/KkGby/). Note how all three images have their own sliding text.

References:

[**jQuery selectors**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)
[**.hide()**](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)
[**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)
[**.slideDown()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/)
[**.slideUp()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)
[**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
[**authoring jQuery plugins**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Answer (score 2):

Well for starters you `<p>` should be hidden first. `<p style="display:none;">...</p>`

Here is what your code should look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.fn.showFeatureText = function() {
        return this.each(function(){    
            var box = $(this);
            var text = $('p',this);    
            box.hover(function(){
              text.slideDown("slow");
            },function(){
              text.slideUp("fast");
            });        
          });
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.feature_box').showFeatureText();    
    });
</script>

<div>
    <div class="feature_box" align="right">
        <h2><a href="#">Cart Details</a></h2>
        <p style="display:none;">
        <a href="#">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident. <BR />
        Qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum<br />
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident. <BR />
        Qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</a></p>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you've initially pulled up the div.

Comment: @Peter. The paragraphs is hidden, not the div. He needs the heading to stay visible.

Comment: great..thnx :) It's working fine..but ther's this other problem now..I want the paragraph to appear ONLY when the mouse is hovered on the link "Cart Details" BUT the para is appearing when I move my mouse over the whole DIV tag's area..I want the paragraph ONLy when mouse is over those two words "Cart Details" 
Dunno how else to explain...How can I achieve that ? I tried setting the width of the div tag but its not working..it makes the para as well as the link "Cart details "to appear on the left side..which is weird..Any suggestion??

Comment: **It is bad practice to use `<p style="display:none;">`** in this case, since search engines will think the text is invisible, and what about text reader? Instead you can use, like the example page, `text.css({ position: 'absolute', top: '57px' }).hide();`

Comment: @Peter, bleh. With a lot of images on the page, the way the example does it you will see all the text initially shown then hidden, resulting in flickering. One, two images maybe it will not be seen, if it's a lot of images, you will definitely see it.